# Oracle: date not valid for month specified in groovy

Tags: string, oracle, date, parsing, groovy

Using RestApi i am trying to fetch response and saving the data into database using groovy and java.

I have field `Allocation Date` where the format i am receiving from RestApi is for example
'"2020-06-30".

So in my java `IData` class i have created method as  `IN_DATE_FORMAT` for input format:

```
public static final DateFormat IN_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

And in groovy class i have created constructor and using this method like below:

```
 def contents = json.Contents as ArrayList
 contents.parallelStream().each { rec ->
 IData data = new IData ()
 def allocDate = rec["Allocation Date"]
            
 data.allocationDate = allocDate  != null ? IData .IN_DATE_FORMAT.parse(allocDate as String) : null
```

When i am running the code i am getting in between few error as

```
ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
```

And i am receiving corrupt date as for example `'31-Apr-20'` which is normally not correct as in April month we dont have date 31. And this value is not coming from RestApi. I dont understand from where this corrupt date value is coming from. Is it because of conversion and parsing the date into String ?
Can we use something like `LocalDate` in my code as this looks risky of parsing date into string ? And i think because of which its trying to store incorrect date value in database which even does not exist and received from RestApi.

Below are my logs for def allocDate = rec["Allocation Date"]:

```
    WARNING: Failed to execute: insert into XXX ( 
                ALLOCATIONDATE
                ) values (                    
                        '31-Apr-20'                    
                    ) 
                 because: ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
    
    10:57:16.103 [Actor Thread 3] WARN XXXX - Failed to execture record due to:ORA-01839: date not valid for month specified
   Allocation Date:- 2020-06-30
   Allocation Date:- 2020-06-25
   Allocation Date:- 2020-07-30
   Allocation Date:- 2020-05-30
   Allocation Date:- 2020-06-25
....
```

Below is my Insert into DB method:

```
private boolean insertIntoDb(Map<String, List<IData>> ricMap) {
        Sql conn = sql(ORACLE)

        conn.withTransaction {            
            ricMap.entrySet().parallelStream().forEach { entry ->
                entry.value.parallelStream().forEach { val ->
                    String values = """                    
                    ${nullStr(val.allocationDate != null ? DbConnCfg.ORACLE_DATE_FORMAT.format(val.allocationDate) : null)}  
                   """                    
                }
            }
        }
```

In `DbConnCfg` class i have defined ORACLE_DATE_FORMAT method as below:

```
public static final DateFormat ORACLE_DATE_FORMAT = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
```

Comment: Could you please place some logs and print what's coming? print contents, allocDate etc

Comment: i have provided in question now

Comment: I'm specifically looking for the logs on the constructor/method where you set data.allocationDate. print contents & allocDate

Comment: yes its the log for that part only where its taking the data from RestApi

Comment: Sorry my mistake i put the logs after i parsed into String...now i put the logs before parsing...

Comment: How the date format is changed between "constructor/method" and "INSERT statement".? Is there any logic in between? Can you please check how it passes to a different date format?

Comment: I have mentioned insert into database method also now ...can you please check i am not understanding if parsing date into string and then insert into db is issue or what other issue is there with date

Answer (score 0):

You can parse a given date by using `Date.parse(format, date)`. In your case, 31 April is parsed as May 1st. I don't know if this will solve your problem.

```
dt1 = '30-Apr-20'
dt2 = '31-Apr-20'

def format(dt) {
    def newDt = new Date().parse("dd-MMM-yy", dt) //reverse-engineers the date, keeps it a Date object
    return newDt.format("yyyy-MM-dd")             //apply the format you wish
}

assert format(dt1) == '2020-04-30'
assert format(dt2) == '2020-05-01'
```

Comment: sorry but i really dont undestand your approach and as i said this date 31-Apr-20 is not coming from RestApi and its somehow getting corrupt i guess during parsing...i cannot simple change the date for example to '2020-05-01'...could be helpful if can modify my approach to give the solution ...thanks

Comment: All I can think is that the date you receive is not in a parseable condition. Show the printout of `rec["Allocation Date"]` before you parse it please. You can also wrap your code in a try-catch, looking for `ParseException`.

Comment: i already edited question and paste the logs for rec["Allocation Date"]

Comment: Ok, so you receive it in the format 'Sun May 31 00:00:00 CEST 2020'. What happens when you do `Date.parseToStringDate("${rec['Allocation Date']}").format('yyyy-MM-dd')` to all the dates ?

Comment: Sorry my mistake i put the logs after i parsed into String...now i put the logs before parsing...

Comment: I have mentioned insert into database method also now ...can you please check